# Center background image

Tags: html, css

The design I have for my site involves a circle-slideshow in the middle of my page. The background image is a repeative circle which doesnt move, but.. I cant centre it with my circle to match..

I'm using a 1:1 background-image to make it perfectly round. To make the site run perfectly on all browsers I'm using

```
background-position: center top;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: scroll;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

The result I got is similar to the fiddle I made here:
http://jsfiddle.net/LG5r9/1/

The smaller blue circle(with black border) has to be in the middle of the bigger blue circle. How do I fix this problem? I'm pretty clueless to be honest.

EDIT: I'm pretty stupid. It centers perfectly if you use your browser in a 1:1 resolution. Is it possible to fix it so that it's compatible with any browser settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having:

```
background-position: center top;
```

Just use:

```
background-position: center;
```

Also for firefox you need:

```
-moz-background-position: fixed;
```

If you want to center the other div tehn you can use position absolute like this:

```
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
margin-left: -100px;
margin-top: -100px;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Hive7/LG5r9/5/

Comment: Ah thanks! On my live version the picture still looks a little bit off, but that's probably just the picture not being perfectly centered.

Comment: I don't get it @Janwillem Dooms, This answer was just a rewrite of mine!

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS tables for this!

#### css

```css
html, body{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    /* you might want an additional container instead of setting
     * the display: table; directly on <body>, depending on use case */
    display: table;
    background-image:url('http://www.osa-opn.org/opn/media/Images/AfterImages/13-jan-01.jpg?width=2400&height=2400&ext=.jpg');
    background-position: center; /* as mentioned in other answers */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: scroll;
}
.container {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle; /* only works because of table-cell display */
}
#image {
    border-radius: 50em;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

#### html

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <img src="http://www.osa-opn.org/opn/media/Images/AfterImages/13-jan-01.jpg?width=2400&height=3300&ext=.jpg" alt="" id="image" />
    </div>
</body>
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/LG5r9/6/

Comment: Good, but not necessary in this instance as we know the dimensions of `#image`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to center both your background image and your foreground image:

Here you go:
http://jsfiddle.net/LG5r9/4/

Here's how to center a (foreground) element in the middle of the screen:

```
#image {
border-radius: 50em;
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
position:absolute;
top:50%;
margin-top:-100px;
left:50%;
margin-left:-100px;
}
```

heres how to center a background image: `background-position:center`

Comment: I'd rather not use margin's though. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Why not? Since you know the width and height of the image, this is the simplest way to do it cross-browser. It's far better than using tables as you have.